# Query Problem in getting top viewed posts

Tags: get-posts

I wanted to display top viewed posts by month, I add this [code snip](http://wpsnipp.com/index.php/loop/most-popular-posts-using-views-post-meta/), to form a query and get required 15 posts, but it displays 3-4 posts.Here is my query:

```
global $post;

$args = array(
    'meta_key' => post_views_count,
    'orderby' => meta_value_num,
    'numberposts' => 15,
    'order' => 'DESC',
);

$top_viewed_posts = get_posts( $args );

foreach( $top_viewed_posts as $post ) :
    $mylimit= 30 * 86400;        //To display post for last 30 days 
    $post_age = date('U') - get_post_time('U');
    if ($post_age < $mylimit) {

        if (has_post_thumbnail()) { ?>
            <li>
                <div class="widgetimg">
                    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?></a>
                </div>
                <span class="sidebarviews">Views: <?php echo getPostViews(get_the_ID());?></span>
            </li>
        <?php
        }
    }
endforeach; ?>
```

But when I remove this portion :

```
$mylimit= 30 * 86400;        //To display post for last 30 days 
$post_age = date('U') - get_post_time('U');
if ($post_age < $mylimit) {
```

It displays correctly 15 posts.

Please suggest!

Comment: Can you indent your code appropriately so that it's readable? It's difficult to read in its current form. Also have you verified that you actually have 15 posts in the current month to display?

Comment: I suppose you have 3/4 posts a month? In that case the code does exactly what it's supposed to do; "Order the posts by month descending by post count with a limit of 15 posts a month".

Comment: Also, you query 15 posts, and after that, you check wich of them are from last month.

Comment: @TomJNowell I initially had 13 posts, it used to display 2 posts then. Now, I changed that to 15, its 3 posts now

Comment: @MikeMadern, I make around 7-10 posts a day. And that second code snip I showed limits all those posts from current day to last 30 days.

Comment: Then I would deem this an example of the XY problem, perhaps you should ammend your question to ask "How do I show posts from the last month" rather than "I tried to show posts in the last month, here is my solution, but my solution is also broken, give me a solution for my solution"

Comment: The posts you are expecting to see have thumbnails, right?

Comment: @TomJNowell, I am using this same way to retrieve most commented posts by month, so I think there is no need to change my question

Comment: @vancoder, I have thumbnails for all posts. I have designed this for a client who used this theme as photoblog. If you want I can provide a link.

Comment: @10wtaylor I can think of far better ways of doing this that *don't* have the problem you're having, but they would not be valid answers to your question in its current form despite fixing your problem

Comment: Rephrasing the question to "I am trying to do X, this is my attempt to do it using Y, but it didnt work out, how do I do it?" Rather than "I did Y, it didnt work as expected, what went wrong?"

Comment: Also keep in mind this would be more useful to other people if you rephrase it, which means more upvotes, which could be put towards a bounty in the future

Comment: @TomJNowell, Ok thanks I agree with you! So, should I change this question as it is left unanswered? I afraid that most member will ask for way I am using to retrieve top viewed posts, then I will have change whole technique of which I don't have any idea now.

Comment: ask the question to your original problem